# RPM returns badly printed OS package of a path

Tags: linux, rpm, opensuse, dependencies

I'm trying to find a related OS package of a path. I use `rpm` for that. For example:

```
> /bin/rpm -qf --queryformat '[%{NAME}]' /usr/bin/tcsh
tcsh
```

But I noticed that there are packages that are printed badly:

```
/bin/rpm -qf --queryformat '[%{NAME}]' /usr/bin/wget
wgetwget-openssl1
```

There is no such OS package `wgetwget-openssl1`. But there is `wget-openssl1`. What am I doing wrong? Why it prints it like that?

Another example of badly print:

```
/bin/rpm -qf --queryformat "[%{NAME}]" /usr/bin/curl
curlcurl-openssl1
```

Should be: `curel-openssl1`.

I noticed that it happened only with packages `(.*)-openssl1` like:

```
> /bin/rpm -qf --queryformat "[%{NAME}]" /usr/bin/mailx
mailxmailx-openssl1
```

As I'm using this command in automated script which wants to find the related OS package, How can I make it work? Is there another `--queryformat` I could use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your command is finding multiple results, but not separating them. Add `\n` to the format string:

```
$ rpm -qf --queryformat "[%{NAME}]\n" /usr/bin/mailx
mailx
mailx-openssl1
```